# how to make a popup div with jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i want to popup a div when i click on a link my popup with jQuery, i do not like the SharePoint Modal dialog. i tried with jQuery wit no way any help please.

```
  <a href="">my modal</a>
   <div id="dialog">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td width="150px">Select Excel File :
             </td>
             <td width="600px">
                 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="441px" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"  
                Text="Upload Excel Data" />
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                 <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" 
                OnClick="btnDownload_Click" Text="Dowload Data As Excel" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: you can edit the visualization of the SharePoint Modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery UI**

If you want to use jQuery modal dialog then first include jQueryUI references.

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js
```

Once this is done. You can use following to invoke the dialog

```
$("#dialog" ).dialog();
```

**Using SharePoint Modal Dialog**

```
<div id="dialog">
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td width="150px">Select Excel File :
         </td>
         <td width="600px">
             <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="441px" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click"  
            Text="Upload Excel Data" />
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
             <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" 
            OnClick="btnDownload_Click" Text="Dowload Data As Excel" />
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">      
    function openHelloDialog() {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
        options.title = "Dialog Title";
        options.width = 600;
        options.height = 400;
        options.html = document.getElementById('dialog');

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
</script>
```